# How to forward message without user source? Telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegraf

Im creating broadcast in telegram(using telegraf framework), and i need to send message from one user to all users, i can do this with .forwardMessage(chatId) but i need add buttons to message, and i dont want to see text *forward from someone*. I can create very big switch with checking what type of content is this and realise .sendMessage for all type of content, but its very shitcode. Maybe someone nows how to forward message without "forward from someone" and add keyboard to this messsage and at same time do this without 1024 kilometers of shitcode.

I will be very happy if someone knows the answer

p.s
sorry for my english

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `.copyMessage` and then `.editMessageMarkup`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.